# Toggle class and change size on an element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to have a div change its properties on a click function. Some of the properties I am changing with a call to `toggleClass()` which is fine and works great. However I also want to resize the div based on the size of the viewport. In order to have access to those numbers I am changing the `width` and `height` with `jQuery`. This command looks like this:

```
$('.box').click( function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('box--grow', 0);
  $(this).css('width', w * .9);
  $(this).css('height', h * .9);
});
```

**EDIT** I want the `height` and `width` to go back to 100%.

I tried using the `toggle` class but that caused the entire div to disappear, and this solution doesn't work because when I click the div again the class is removed but the height is the same.

I am looking for a way to toggle this or to get the viewport width within the `css`. I tried both approaches but couldn't get anything to what I am looking for.

Comment: What is going to happen for the size on the 2nd click?

Comment: `$(this).toggleClass('box--grow', 0);` Why are you passing 0 to `toggleClass()`???

Comment: @Pangloss I want the `height` and `width` to go back to 100%, sorry I didn't really mention that.

Comment: i edited my answer, let me know if it works else could you maybe make a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the window size first, and then put everything into combined `.ready()` and `.resize()` functions, to make it responsive.

```
function myfunction() {
    var w = $(window).width();
    var h = $(window).height();

    $('.box').click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('box--grow')) {
            $(this).removeClass('box--grow');
            $(this).css({
                'width': '',
                'height': ''
            });
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('box--grow');
            $(this).css({
                'width': w * .9,
                'height': h * .9
            });
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(myfunction);
$(window).on('resize', myfunction);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajxz1k6h/)

Comment: A lot of these answers worked but I went with this, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

why not using CSS VH and VW values?

CSS:

```
.my90Class{
   width: 90vw;
   height: 90vh;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.box').click( function() {
   $(this).toggleClass("my90Class");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the class with:

```
$(this).hasClass('box--grow')
```

Then to remove the class:

```
$(this).removeClass('box--grow');
```

And to add it back again:

```
$(this).addClass('box--grow');
```

The end would look like this save the original width and height before the event so you can add it back again:

```
var oldwidth = $('.box').css('width');
var oldheight = $('.box').css('height');

$('.box').click( function() {
  if($(this).hasClass('box--grow')) {
   $(this).removeClass('box--grow');
   $('.box').css('width', oldwidth);
   $('.box').css('height', oldheight);
  } else { 
   $(this).addClass('box--grow');
  }
});
```

untested but it would probably work

Comment: I can toggle the class just fine, I want the `height` and `width` to go back down to 100%

Comment: so what is the value of w and h? the question is toggle css without using toggleclass i did that for you. Also i added a method that does what you want i hope